# No padding displayed even after correct code

Tags: html, css, html-lists, padding

As a total beginner, I am making a website based totally on html and css... I'm having a problem though - the a tags in list aren't getting padded whatever I try to do in both the codes... I've tried to think of a reason, but cannot come up with one. Please see the html and css codes for the error. thanks.
[the website image looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytkwf.jpg)
the html & css code looks like this:

```css
 ul{
        display: block;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: black;
        }
        li{
        float: left;
        }
        li a{
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 16 px;
        }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
        <title>abc's official website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/articles.html">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="/books.html">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="/awards.html">Awards</a></li>
                <li><a href="/shortstories.html">Shortstories</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <p>Welcome to <br><span> abc's</span> <br>official website</p>
        </div>
         
    </body>
    </html>
```

but after you look at the website image, (I have tried ctrl+s on html and css and then running it again on the live server but no effect) there is no spacing or padding in the horizontal list. Also, I looked up most of my code from https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_menu
but I keep getting the same squeezed list result. Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: This is just a typo - you have a space between `16` and `px`. You can't have a space before the unit so it should be `16px`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You simply needed `padding: 16px` instead of `padding: 16 px`.

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <title>abc's official website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/articles.html">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="/books.html">Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="/awards.html">Awards</a></li>
      <li><a href="/shortstories.html">Shortstories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <p>Welcome to <br><span> abc's</span> <br>official website</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but FYI the correct action for low quality questions (like this one) is to flag them or if a question need more details then you could ask for more information in the comments. Or simply just move on to well-asked questions :) Otherwise we are just encouraging more poor questions :) Please see the "Answer well-asked questions" section in [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you so much, i was baffled at this point!